# How to make salesforce SDK work in .NET framework 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, salesforce, .net-4.5

I am integrating salesforce with visual studio using developerforce.force nuget. I was able to successfully do it on Net Framework 4.5. But, My solution is in NET 4 framework and salesforce nuget works only on NET 4.5 framework.

1. Is there any way I can make salesforce nugets work on .Net Framework 4.0?
2. Is there any way I can add a reference of a project with .Net 4.5 on 4.0 i.e., make .Net 4.0 forward compatible.

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the [Version History](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeveloperForce.Force/) ypu'll see 2 older versions.  Have you checked which Framework version they use?

Comment: I tried all three versions. No matter which version for 4.0, I am getting the error:

 type or namespace name 'Salesforce' could not be found

Comment: Wade Wegner, who created this nuget himself said that he removed the support for 4.0.

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/issues/35

Is there any way around this ?